# Google Sheets API v4

Tags: google-sheets

Just notice the Google Sheets API v4 has been released.

As i got a web app running with the Google Sheets API version 3,
wondering if there is any deprecation plan of the such version?

Sorry for my poor English.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a support question for Google, not for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to be a Googler to know this. In [Spreadsheet v3 docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#terminology_used_in_this_guide) Google announced that v3 will eventually be deprecated like v1 and v2:

> We strongly recommend all developers use the Google Sheets API v4.
>
> Version 3.0 (the version described here), is documented for legacy
>   purposes only, and will eventually be deprecated. We no longer
>   document v1 or v2.
>
> Versions 1 and 2 are no longer available as of October 20, 2012.

Hence, this [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration) is for you. Hope that helps.